# How can primordial helium be formed before atoms?

Tags: universe

In my physics textbook it describes the events at the beginning of the Universe. I'm confused about the order at a certain point. It says that at some point primordial helium is created, then it says that later atoms are formed. Isn't primordial helium made of atoms?

Thank you :)

Comment: It just means that the other elements were created afterwards. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis#Sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primordial helium was not created as neutral atoms. It was created only as atomic nuclei when the baryonic matter was still ionized. Only much later the electrons started to recombine with the atomic nuclei (hydrogen and helium) and only at that point the neutral hydrogen and helium are born. But the nuclei were there earlier.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thank you. Am I right in thinking that it would be called plasma in that state?

Comment: @Elise Yes, this state is called plasma.